# Sending webforms: envelope sender not allowed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a website with a webform which users can use to contact a company. The webform internally creates an email in PHP using PHPMailer and is sending this email via SMTP to the company.

The company has a customer-management-system which identifies the user by looking at the sender of the  email. Which means I couldn't send the email from the form from "form@example.com" to "customer-relations@example.com", but need to send it from "customeremail@customerdomain.com" to "customer-relations@example.com".

This worked for some years now, but since some time, we get the error-message:

```
"envelope sender not allowed customeremail@customerdomain.com"
```

for example from emails from @gmail.com. Other domains still work.

I understand that it is not good practice to "fake" the sender of the email to make the identification of the customer-management-system work. The developer of the customer-management-systems are not able to offer a solution yet (no comment on that...), so perhaps there are any ideas here which we could try to make this work?

Comment: Yeah, that's just broken behaviour by your CMS, and I'm not surprised it's being rejected. Are you sure that it's the envelope sender that needs this setting and not the from address? Even then, it's still forgery and you shouldn't be attempting that. The return path serves a strict technical purpose (where to send bounces), whereas the from address serves a more semantic one that is somewhat (DMARC notwithstanding) disconnected from the envelope sender.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the envelope sender and the from address are 2 different things? I'm just setting $PHPMailer->From, the rest is done by the PHPMailer-class (which sets the envelope sender then I suppose).

Comment: But as I understand you wouldn't recommend setting "from" and "envelope" to 2 different domains?

Comment: They are quite different things, though they do most often end up with the same value. You can use different domains for each, but that will often lead to DMARC problems. For example, if you use a mailing list service, the return path will often point at one of their domains, but the from address will be your domain. PHPMailer sets the sender from the `From` property *by default*, but you can override that by setting the `Sender` property. Don't be tempted to try to add a return-path header yourself; that's the receiver's job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see we need to get this CMS fixed soon...